# Java Mail FolderClosedException

Tags: java, email, imap

A little piece of Java code is used to read an IMAP mailbox for "bunced" emails, and set the flags in our database. We found that the code will throws "FolderClosedException" when processing some email. Here is a function to test this:

```
private void processStore(Store store) throws MessagingException {
    Folder folder=store.getDefaultFolder();

    Folder inboxfolder=folder.getFolder("INBOX");

    inboxfolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] msgs=inboxfolder.getMessages();

    FetchProfile fp=new FetchProfile();
    fp.add("Subject");
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
//  problematic
//  fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);


    inboxfolder.fetch(msgs,fp);

    for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;++i){
        System.out.println(inboxfolder.isOpen());
        System.out.println(msgs[i].getSubject());
    }
}
```

What we found here is, for those problematic emails, if we comment out the line marked as "problematic", every thing works fine. But once we uncomment it, `inboxfolder.isOpen()` prints `false` and `msgs[i].getSubject()` throws `FolderClosedException`.

We recon this could be a problem of Java Mail, or our mail server (postfix). So are there anyone knows why this could happen, and/or how to diagnose and figure out what causes this problem?

Comment: Please turn up debugging and find the IMAP protocol exchange. There will likely be a command like 'blah fetch 123234 (header.fields ("subject") envelope)' and then a response like 'blah NO error message here'. The error message is important.

Comment: Can you show me how to turn it on?

Comment: Use tcpdump, or see the first item in the javamail debugging FAQ:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#debug